# Is it appropriate to compare a value against a Mean (average) which also includes that value?

Tags: mean

For example for arguments sake lets say I have the production output of car manufacturers (Ford, Nissan, Toyota, Hyundai, Renault, Tesla) and for a particular category it makes up 40% of the annual output across all manufactures.

Would it be appropriate to compare the output of Ford in that category against that 40% or should I exclude Ford from the overall percentage to make the comparison more valid/robust?

Is there a problem with comparing means/averages

- (Ford + Nissan + Toyota + Hyundai + Renault + Tesla) compared to Ford
  or should it be
- (Nissan + Toyota + Hyundai + Renault + Tesla) compared to Ford

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am looking for advice on whether its appropriate/sound when comparing means/averages to do so while including a component that was itself used in calculating that mean.

Comment: These are both acceptable and tell you different things. There is no "one, right" way to do things around here :)

Comment: When you say it tells you different things. I'm not sure I understand what those differences are though. Forgive me while I type/think it out. By including the component (aka ford) when calculating the mean I can refer to industry mean but what can I say if I exclude ford, then I'm comparing Ford to its competitions. Is that about right?